# How to start a program from remote powershell console?

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

In the webgui for defaultapp, you can click a button to start the selected app in the drop down.

What command is hidden under that button to start the universal app? I would like to do this from a remote console programatically.

Also, is the source code available for the defaultapp/webgui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PowerShell to set an app as startup, run in headless mode etc.
Find the details of connecting it with PowerShell here: https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PowerShell.htm

Also running in headless mode saves more memory, power, faster boot.

Also command line utils for enabling startup process:
https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/tools/CommandLineUtils.htm

-> Default App Sample: https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/IoTCoreDefaultApp

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: +1 for showing me the source code. But I dont think they start the app by setting is a the startup app and then rebooting the Pi? We are looking for starting the app directly, without setting it as the startup app.